# Create a custom diagram

Tags: plotting, charts

Suppose we have the following list with a row of integer numbers

```
data = {0, 0, -1, 1, 1, 2, 9, -2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 9, 9, -1, 0, 9, 2}
```

Each integer corresponds to a classification number. Now I want to create the following custom diagram:

[image]

If for example, the `data` list contains 20 integers then the circle should be divided into 20 sectors of equal area. Then each sector should be colored according to the value of the integer. The color code is the following:

-1 ---> yellow

-2 ---> purple

0 ---> green

1 ---> blue

2 ---> red

9 ---> cyan

The sectors should start from 12 o'clock and follow and clockwise orientation. Ideally, an arrow should indicate the direction.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you get when you run `DeleteDuplicates[data]` for your actual data?

Comment: @kglr I get a second list but I do not want to remove any data. I beleive that the issue is due to the boundaries. How can we have white boudnaries in each sector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
coloring = Thread[{-1, -2, 0, 1, 2, 9} -> {Yellow, Purple, Green, Blue, Red, Cyan}]; 
data = {0, 0, -1, 1, 1, 2, 9, -2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 9, 9, -1, 0, 9, 2};
ca = ConstantArray[1, Length @ data];

PieChart[ca, 
 SectorOrigin -> {{Pi/2, "Clockwise"}, 0}, 
 ChartStyle -> (data /. coloring), 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[{data, Range[Length@data]}, {"RadialCenter", "RadialOutside"}],
 ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[White]
```

[image]

Use `"RadialCallout"` instead of `"RadialOutside"` to get

[image]

Use `SectorOrigin -> {{Pi/2, "Clockwise"}, 1}` to get

[image]

**Update:** Remove labels and add an arrow and legend:

```
PieChart[ca, 
 SectorOrigin -> {{π/2, "Clockwise"}, 0}, 
 ChartStyle -> (data /. coloring), ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[White], 
 Epilog -> {Line[{{0, 1}, {0, 1.2}}],
   Arrowheads[Medium], Arrow[1.1 {Cos@#, Sin@#} & /@ Subdivide[π/2, π/4, 10]]},
 ChartLegends -> (SwatchLegend[#2, #] & @@ Transpose[List @@@ coloring])]
```

[image]

Add label to one of the sectors:

```
PieChart[MapAt[Labeled[#, "this is\na test", "RadialCallout"] &, ca, {13}], 
 SectorOrigin -> {{π/2, "Clockwise"}, 0}, 
 ChartStyle -> (data /. coloring), ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[White], 
 Epilog -> {Line[{{0, 1}, {0, 1.2}}], Arrowheads[Medium], 
   Arrow[1.1 {Cos@#, Sin@#} & /@ Subdivide[π/2, π/4, 10]]}, 
 ChartLegends -> (SwatchLegend[#2, #] & @@ 
    Transpose[List @@@ coloring])]
```

[image]

```
positions = {5, 13, 17};
labels = {"label5", "label13", "label17"};

ca[[positions]] = MapThread[Labeled[#, #2, "RadialCallout"] &, 
  {ca[[positions]], labels}];

PieChart[ca, SectorOrigin -> {{π/2, "Clockwise"}, 0}, 
 ChartStyle -> (data /. coloring), ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[White], 
 Epilog -> {Line[{{0, 1}, {0, 1.2}}], Arrowheads[Medium], 
   Arrow[1.1 {Cos@#, Sin@#} & /@ Subdivide[π/2, π/4, 10]]}, 
 ChartLegends -> (SwatchLegend[#2, #] & @@ Transpose[List @@@ coloring])]
```

[image]

Comment: Please, see my edit.

Comment: I suspect that the problem is the fact that there are black solid lines at the boundaries of each sector. Is there a way to have white boundaries?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z, try adding the option  `ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[White]`.

Comment: That fixed the issue with the dark colors! Now is there a way to mark the origin with a vertical line (as in my initial plot) and also add an arrow indicating the direction of sectors?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z, please see the update.

Comment: Perfect!just one last question: is there a way to print a line indicating a specific integer of the list, e.g., indicate the sector of the 13 integer with a label?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z, i added an example re adding a label to a specific sector.

Comment: Thanks but what I intended was to add a custom lable (text label, e.g., "This is a test...") not the number "13".

Comment: replace `Labeled[#, 13, "RadialCallout"] &` with `Labeled[#, "This is a test", "RadialCallout"] &`

Comment: Is there a way to add multiple text labels, let's say at positions 13, 15 and 19?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z, updated with an example for labels in multiple positions.

Comment: Perfect! Lastly, can we customize the size and fonts of the text lables? Andl also if some labels are on top of each other can we do somthing about it?