# Creating a custom curved axis around a pie chart

Tags: plotting, graphics, labeling

In a recent [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211247/create-a-custom-diagram), we have seen (thanks to @kglr) how to create a custom pie chart

```
Clear["Global`*"];

coloring = 
Thread[{-1, -2, 0, 1, 2, 9} -> {Yellow, Purple, Green, Blue, Red, Cyan}];
data = {0, 0, -1, 1, 1, 2, 9, -2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 9, 9, -1, 0, 9, 2};

PieChart[ConstantArray[1, Length@data], 
SectorOrigin -> {{\[Pi]/2, "Clockwise"}, 1}, 
ChartStyle -> (data /. coloring), ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[None]]
```

[image]

The above approach works very well when the dat file contains a list of integer numbers.

Now let's consider a two-dimensional data where the first row indicates the time, while the second row is the classification integer.

```
data2 = {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, -1}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}, {6, 2}, {7, 9}, 
         {8, -2}, {9, 2}, {10, 1}, {11, 1}, {12, 1}, {13, 0}, 
         {14, 0}, {15, 9}, {16, 9}, {17, -1}, {18, 0}, {19, 9}, 
         {20, 2}};
```

I would like the following: wrap a curved axis around the pie chart indicating the time, let's say by printing the corresponding time every two steps (i.e., printing the values 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, ...) above the corresponding sectors of the pie chart. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
coloring = Thread[{-1, -2, 0, 1, 2, 9} -> {Yellow, Purple, Green, Blue, Red, Cyan}];
time = data2[[All, 1]];
data = data2[[All, 2]];

labels = ConstantArray["", Length@time];
labels[[2 ;; ;; 2]] = time[[2 ;; ;; 2]];

PieChart[ConstantArray[1, Length@data], 
 SectorOrigin -> {{π/2, "Clockwise"}, 1}, 
 ChartStyle -> (data /. coloring), ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[None], 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[labels, "RadialOutside"]]
```

[image]

Add the options `PolarAxes -> {True, False}`, `PolarTicks -> {Automatic, 
  None}` and `TicksStyle -> FontOpacity -> 0` to get

[image]

Comment: Nice! but my actual data contain about 2000 integers, so when I print the time labels is a real mesh. Is there a way to print only let's say 10 or 20 equally spaced labels?

Comment: That does not seem to work. If for example, I use `Riffle[time[[2 ;; ;; 4]], "", {1, -1, 2}]` then the time lables are misplaced.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z, good catch. I will update with a fix in a moment.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z, please see the new version.

Comment: Hmm, the question remains. What if I want to print only let's say 5 or 8 equally spaced time labels?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z, change `labels[[2 ;; ;; 2]] = time[[2 ;; ;; 2]];` to, say,  `labels[[5 ;; ;; 5]] = time[[5 ;; ;; 5]];` to label sectors `5`, `10, `15`, `20`...