# Custom labels in a pie chart

Tags: graphics, labeling

Using @kglr's approach (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211247/create-a-custom-diagram)) we can create the following pie chart

```
coloring = Thread[{-1, -2, 0, 1, 2, 9} -> {Yellow, Purple, Green, Blue, Red, Cyan}];
data = {0, 0, -1, 1, 1, 2, 9, -2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 9, 9, -1, 0, 9, 2};
ca = ConstantArray[1, Length@data];

positions = {5, 13, 17};
labels = {"label5", "label13", "label17"};

ca[[positions]] = MapThread[Labeled[#, #2, "RadialCallout"] &, {ca[[positions]], labels}];

plot = PieChart[ca, SectorOrigin -> {{\[Pi]/2, "Clockwise"}, 0}, 
       ChartStyle -> (data /. coloring), ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[White]]
```

[image]

My main question: is there a way to explicitly define the size and fonts of the text labels? Perhaps adding `LabelStyle -> {14, Bold, Blue}]`
My secondary question: in my actual data file, there are cases in which the labels are too close and the corresponding text is overlapping (see the example below). Can we do something about it?

[image]

**EDIT**

Using @kglr's solution I get the following

[image]

As we can see, the borders of the frame are overlapping each other.

Comment: `LabelStyle -> {14, Bold, Blue}` or `LabelStyle -> Directive[14, Bold, Blue]` should work for styling labels. For positioning labels to avoid crowding see [this answer by Silvia](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9082/125)

Comment: @kglr Great! Also is there a way to insert a frame around the text labels? I know that this is possible with `Framed` but I do not know where to insert it in your code.

Comment: define `labels` as `labels = Framed /@ {"label5", "label13", "label17"};` or (to style the frame and the backgorund)  as `labels = Framed[#,Background->LightBlue, FrameStyle->Red]&/@ {"label5", "label13", "label17"};`

Comment: In Callout, every bit of information of the label is important for it to figure out the proper spacing. If possible, don't use Style wrapper on the labels. This should help: `ca[[positions]] = 
 MapThread[
  Callout[#, Framed@#2, LabelStyle -> {#3, 16}, 
    Appearance -> {"Line"}] &, {ca[[positions]], labels, 
   data[[positions]] /. coloring}]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I learned from [this answer by rcollyer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/144581/125) that we can use `Callout` with `PieChart` in versions 11.1+.

```
coloring = Thread[{-1, -2, 0, 1, 2, 9} -> {Yellow, Purple, Green, Blue, Red, Cyan}];

SeedRandom[123]
data = RandomChoice[{-1, -2, 0, 1, 2, 9}, 200];
ca = ConstantArray[1, Length @ data];
```

Some positions and associated labels:

```
positions = {1, 2, 3, 40, 170, 171, 172, 173};
labels = Style[#, 16] & /@ {"label1", "label2", "label3", "label40", 
    "label170", "label171", "label172", "label173"};
```

Wrap `1`s in `positions` in `ca` with `Callout` using associated labels as callout label and style each label based on corresponding part of `data`:

```
ca[[positions]] = MapThread[Callout[#, Style[#2, #3], Appearance -> {"Line"}] &, 
   {ca[[positions]], labels, data[[positions]] /. coloring}];
```

Place the epilog inside the to avoid overlaps with the sector labels:

```
plot = PieChart[ca, SectorOrigin -> {{π/2, "Clockwise"}, 1}, 
  ChartStyle -> (data /. coloring), ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[White],
  ImageSize -> Large, 
  Epilog -> {Line[{{0, 1}, {0, .8}}], Arrowheads[Medium], 
    Arrow[.9 {Cos@#, Sin@#} & /@ Subdivide[π/2, π/6, 10]]}]
```

[image]

Use `Style[Framed@#, 16] &` when defining `labels` and add the option `ImagePadding -> 20` in `PieChart` to get

[image]

Comment: I can reproduce your results with only one difference (see my edit). When I use `Framed` the borders of the frames overlapping each other, while in your plot they do not (there is a white gap between them). Why?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z, play with larger setting for  `ImageSize`. You might also want to add the option `ContentPadding ->False` in `Framed`.